# Identify number of occurrence of any combination of equal elements in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a mock dataframe, df1 with 6 columns and 5 rows, i.e., with shape (5 x 6).

Each column represents the price of an area, and rows are time.

```
   DK1   DK2   NO1   NO2   NO3   NO4
0  10    10    12    15    15    10
1  15    10    15    10    10    10
2  15    15    15    15    15    15
3  10    10    12    15    15    10
4  10    10    10    10    15    15
```

Now, I want to identify - in each row - the areas with the same price as the first column "DK1", and then being able to sum up how often any combination of columns are equal, meaning that my desired output for this would be:

```
       Combo                  Occurrence
0   DK1-DK2-NO4                   2
1   DK1-DK2-NO1-NO2-NO3-NO4       1
2   DK1-NO1                       1
3   DK1-DK2-NO1-NO2               1
```

Preferably, the solution should be applicable to any sized DataFrame. I started trying with the .apply() method, but couldn't quite get started. Hope you can help.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare DataFrame by first column by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), then use matrix multiplication by [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with columns names with separator and last count with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and convert to `DataFrame`:

```
df = (df.eq(df['DK1'], axis=0)
        .dot(df.columns + ',')
        .str[:-1]
        .value_counts()
        .rename_axis('Combo')
        .reset_index(name='Occurrence'))
print (df)
                     Combo  Occurrence
0              DK1,DK2,NO4           2
1                  DK1,NO1           1
2          DK1,DK2,NO1,NO2           1
3  DK1,DK2,NO1,NO2,NO3,NO4           1
```

EDIT: For groups is possible create dictionary by all values and then call `replace`:

```
s = df.columns.to_series()
s.index = s.index.str.replace('\d+','', regex=True)

d = s.groupby(level=0).agg(','.join).to_dict()
d = {v:k for k, v in d.items()}
print (d)
{'DK1,DK2': 'DK', 'NO1,NO2,NO3,NO4': 'NO'}

df = (df.eq(df['DK1'], axis=0)
        .dot(df.columns + ',')
        .str[:-1]
        .value_counts()
        .rename_axis('Combo')
        .reset_index(name='Occurrence'))

df['Combo'] = df['Combo'].replace(d, regex=True)
print (df)
        Combo  Occurrence
0      DK,NO4           2
1     DK1,NO1           1
2  DK,NO1,NO2           1
3       DK,NO           1
```

Comment: Wow pretty one. I was coming up with a way less beautiful one

Comment: @jezrael can you help me with some visual clearing up - is it possible to merge areas in e.g., DK if the occurrence contains all areas that have DK in them?

By this, row 0, would be "DK-NO4" instead of "DK1-DK2-NO4".
Hope you can help.

Comment: @JeppeBay - Fast hack should be replace `DK1-DK2` to `DK`, is it possible?

Comment: Would like it to be applicable to both DK, NO and eventually other areas as well. But I only have 4 possible combinations in my actual dataset, so fast hack shouldn't be that much work I guess. Thanks!