# Identify number of occurrence grouped by 'Year' - continued

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pandas-loc

This is a continuation of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66779082/identify-number-of-occurrence-of-any-combination-of-equal-elements-in-dataframe).

Now, I want to have these occurrences grouped by year so that the output would become something like:

```
        Combo  Occurrence (2017)    Occurrence (2018)    Occurrence (2019)   Occurrence (2020)
0      DK,NO4           2                   x                   x                   x
1     DK1,NO1           1                   x                   x                   x
2  DK,NO1,NO2           1                   x                   x                   x
3       DK,NO           1                   x                   x                   x
```

The input data looks like this:

```
      Year  Month  Day  Weekday   NO1  ...    SE3    SE4     FI    DK1    DK2
0      2017      1    1        7  28.4  ...  24.03  24.03  24.03  20.96  20.96
1      2017      1    1        7  28.2  ...  25.05  25.05  25.05  25.05  25.05
2      2017      1    1        7  28.0  ...  25.05  25.05  25.05  25.05  25.05
3      2017      1    1        7  28.0  ...  23.19  23.19  23.19  16.03  16.03
4      2017      1    1        7  28.0  ...  24.10  24.10  24.10  16.43  16.43
...     ...    ...  ...      ...   ...  ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
35063  2020     12   31        4  31.0  ...  31.00  58.04  35.32  89.35  89.35
35064  2020     12   31        4  24.8  ...  24.84  54.45  24.84  56.70  56.70
35065  2020     12   31        4  24.8  ...  24.77  51.18  28.00  52.44  52.44
35066  2020     12   31        4  24.6  ...  24.61  45.84  26.55  51.86  51.86
35067  2020     12   31        4  24.1  ...  24.07  24.07  24.07  78.66  78.66
```

Comment: How looks input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is convert all columns with no processing strings to `index` and then is used [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) for counts values per years:

```
df = df.set_index(['Year','Month','Day','Weekday'])

df = (df.eq(df['DK1 Up'], axis=0)
        .dot(df.columns + ',')
        .str[:-1]
        .to_frame('Combo')
        .groupby('Year')['Combo']
        .value_counts()
        .unstack(0, fill_value=0)
        .add_prefix('Occurrence ')
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index()
        )
print (df)
                             Combo  Occurrence 2017  Occurrence 2020
0  DK1 Up,DK1 Down,DK2 Up,DK2 Down                2                0
1                    DK1 Up,DK2 Up                3                5
```

Comment: Can you help me with how to sort it, so that the "Combo" with the most total occurrences is listed at the top with decreasing total occurrences?

Comment: @JeppeBay - so need sorting each column with years? It is problem, because there is changed order of all values - like `print (df.sort_values('Occurrence 2017'))`, `print (df.sort_values('Occurrence 2019'))`

Comment: I was thinking that I would sum over the row to a separate column, let's call it "Sum" and then sort for this

Comment: @JeppeBay - So use `df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)` and then `df.sort_values('sum')`

Comment: @JeppeBay - So is not posssible use `df['Combo'] = df['Combo'].replace(d, regex=True)` here?

Comment: Yes, I saw that I had commented that line out. But thank you anyway!